# Converter uma string de números numa palavra

Tags: python-2.7

Eu preciso de fazer uma função que recebe uma string composta por algarismos entre 2-9 e que o output são letras, ou seja, basicamente a função vai funcionar como um teclado de um telemóvel, onde o número '2' vai coincidir com o 'A', o '22' vai coincidir com o 'B', até ao '9999' coincidir com o 'Z'. Por exemplo:

```
>>> def teclas('22 2 333 33')
"CAFE"
```

Os valores inseridos nos argumentos podem "dar a volta", no sentido em que se for inserido '2222', a letra voltará será 'A', '22222' a letra será 'B', etc. Tal como funciona num telemóvel com teclas.
Neste momento tenho um dicionário onde atribuo todos os números às letras correspondentes assim:

```
dic={'2':'A', '22':'B', '222':'C', '3':'D'....}
```

A minha dúvida é como faço para que no caso de ser inserido '2222' como argumento, lhe seja atribuído novamente o valor 'A' (não sei como faço o programa "dar a volta").

Comment: Bem vindo a comunidade SOpt. Não ficou claro para mim, a leitura de números não será um dicionário direto? No caso, fornecer '2222' será o mesmo que fornecer '2' e fornecer '22222' será o mesmo que fornecer '22'?

Comment: Exatamente, se imaginarmos que estamos a escrever num telemóvel com teclas, ficando a clicar na tecla '2' repetidamente fará com que as letras mudem consecutivamente, no programa é isso que tem que acontecer, para no caso de ser introduzido o valor '2222' voltar a ler como letra 'A'.

Comment: Ah! Você quer fazer um teclado de celular? Então acho que seu modelo está errado. Você deveria ter um dic para cada tecla. Vou propor uma resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Pelos seus comentários, entendo que você quer modelar um teclado de celular.

Se é assim, ao invés de um dicionário para todas as teclas, você deveria ter um vetor para cada uma.

```
tecla2 = ("A", "B", "C")
tecla3 = ("D", "E", "F")
# demais teclas...
```

Quando o usuário clica em uma tecla, incremente um contador e para descobrir qual a letra faça o módulo do contador com o tamanho do vetor da tecla apertada.

Seu exemplo do "2222", por exemplo, viraria "i += 4". 
Considerando que o vetor começa em 0: pos = (i - 1) % 3.
O resultado seria a posição 0, que tem o "A" como você quer.

Quando o usuário escolher outra tecla, o contador deve ser zerado.

Código-conceito abaixo:

```
letras_tecla_2 = ("a", "b", "c")
letras_tecla_3 = ("d", "e", "f")

def string_from_teclas(teclas):
    ult_tecla = ""
    contador = 0
    string = ""

    for tecla in teclas:
        if tecla == ult_tecla:
            contador += 1
        elif ult_tecla != "":
            contador = contador % 3

            if ult_tecla == "2":
                string += letras_tecla_2[contador]
            elif ult_tecla == "3":
                string += letras_tecla_3[contador]

            contador = 0

        ult_tecla = tecla

    return(string)

print( string_from_teclas("22 222 3 33 ") )
```

Comment: Ipacheco, sua ideia é válida, mas lembrando que esse seu código não cria um dicionário. E que dicionários não possuem indices numéricos. Pelo menos não pelo que eu testei aqui. Modifique seu código para adequar a sua resposta. =)

Comment: Então mas sendo um vetor como ficaria ao chamar a função? Qual seria o argumento?

Comment: @Rubico, desculpe, meu Python é rudimentar, era mais para ser um pseudo-codigo. :-)

Comment: @Stagg, como ninguém deu uma resposta completa, desenvolvi o conceito em um pythonzinho vira-latas. Tenho certeza que você consegue melhorar a partir daí. Por exemplo, colocar todas as tuplas em um hash por tecla e simplificar o if que escolhe a tupla.